# How to create a table based on two variables in MatLab?

Tags: matlab

I have two variables, targetinput and M. Both variables are 4x800.

For example :

Variable targetinput(the first 10 data) :

[image: Variable targetinput]

for the y-axis, 1 = normal, 2 = talking, 3 = laughing and 4 = sleepy.

Variable M(the first 10 data) :

[image]

for the y-axis, 1 = normal, 2 = talking, 3 = laughing and 4 = sleepy.

I want to produce a table with x-axis = targetinput and y-axis = M.

Example of the table that i want to produce :

[image]

This is an example of the first 5 data and the final result will be the total for each row and column. The table that i want to produce can be a new variable in MatLab or a xslx file. 

I am new to MatLab. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Where do you want that table to appear? As a figure on screen? As a separate document (what type)? Please clarify

Comment: How are the resulting values derived? Are you trying to add the values in corresponding elements of the array? Or produce a string that looks like "1+1" for the (Talking,Normal) cell? Or...? I don't see how the numbers in your example output line up with the two inputs.

Comment: as a separate file. xslx would do. im trying to count the number. it would be the total @Schorsch

Comment: based on the input, lets take the targetinput value.for column 1, the value is at 1(normal). thats the target. and then M, which is my result, produce 2(talking). so at the table that i want to create, i just have to put 1, at the right position(normal for target and talking for result). and i want to count for every result @AndrewJanke

Comment: I assume that columns are the items you want to count, and each columns contains exactly one "1" – correct?

Comment: yes. the occurrence in each column @A.Donda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use `find` with two outputs to convert 0/1-encoded data to indices, and then `accumarray` to count occurrences:

```
% determine for each column the index of the row that contains the 1
[targetinput_row, ~] = find(targetargetinputnput);
[M_row, ~] = find(M);
% determine size of table
n_M = size(M, 1);
n_targetinput = size(targetargetinputnput, 1);
% count number of times a pair of row indices occurs
table = accumarray([M_row, targetinput_row], 1, [n_M n_targetinput]);
```